# Dynamic Collapsible List using Knockout

Tags: knockout.js, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm using knockout to generate the data. Using `template` binding:

```
    <ul class="category-list-group" data-bind="template: {name: 'categoryTemplate', foreach: $data.categoryRoot}"></ul>

// --- Template
<script id="categoryTemplate" type="text/html">
    <li data-toggle="collapse" class="collapse" data-bind="css: hasChild, attr: {'data-target': '#' + name().replace(/\s+/g, '') }">
        <a>
            <!-- ko text: name--><!-- /ko -->
        </a>
        <ul class="collapse" data-bind="template: { name: 'categoryTemplate', foreach: children },attr: { id: name().replace(/\s+/g, '') }"></ul>
    </li>
</script>
```

The result is in this [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/7kmmh68p/3/). The odd part is when collapsing the list with child. How can I fix the collapsing list?

Note: I removed the knockout binding in jsfiddle. I just display the html itself

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The collapsing is acting funny because the child click is bubbling up to each parent container. If you move the collapsing to the <a> tags instead of the containers you can fix the collapse behavior.

```
<ul class="category-list-group">
   <li class="collapsed"  aria-expanded="false">
      <a class="has-child" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#Concert">
```

https://jsfiddle.net/7kmmh68p/4/

The only other alternative I've seen is to use some sort of event.stopPropagation() so that the child event fires without bubbling up to all the parent containers.